# What exactly happens after 10.04.2019 with legacy android apps that use GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

We are unsure what exactly will happen with our existing apps that use GCM after 10.04.2019.

1. We have updated the server-side of our apps
2. We have new FCM-based versions of our Android apps.

However:

1. We cannot force the existing users to update their apps
2. Corporate clients might even continue to roll out outdated app
   packages to new users

The information / documentation we found somewhat unclear to what will happen in such cases. Therefore, we decided to put our assumptions into 4 statement and we hope someone will be able to confirm them.

1. It will not be possible to put apps which use the GCM APIS into the Play Store after 10.04.2019
2. It will not be possible to generate a new GCM tokens after 10.04.2019
3. Existing users with existing apps which have already have a GCM token will be able to use their apps normally without being forced to update. E.g. Push notifications and related things will work for them.
4. A user of an existing app which never created a GCM token will not be able to create a GCM token and thus not be able to use any GCM related functions (e.g. Push notifications and related things). Such a user would need to update to the apps in order to e.g. receive push notifications.

I hope someone can confirm above assumptions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service-related question and not a programming question. Contact Google for information regarding changes that they are making to their services and the impact of those changes on your applications.

Comment: Ken, I agree, the question is not technical but I visited the google GCM support site and there they say that product related questions can be put to stack overflow. That's why it is here. FYI: I also used the feedback link on their FAQ page to ask the same question but got no answer so far.

Comment: An off-site location can say whatever they like, but this is not their site. :-) All questions posted here must meet this site's guidelines. This site is specifically for questions related to programming (code) and use of programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, etc.).  Questions about code related to GCM are on-topic here; questions about their plans for features and services are not. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576) for more information.